# Moving the character controller to vector 3 position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently making my Boss AI perform a jump attack against the player, the AI use both navmesh and character controller for movment (navmash only for pathfinding), but I'm having a hard time trying to move the AI to the designated position. here is my code:

```
CharacterController chara;

[SerializeField]
Transform playerTran;

[SerializeField]
float gravity = 3.8f;

[SerializeField]
float jumpForce = 50F;

Vector3 moveVector = Vector3.zero;

[SerializeField]
Transform jumpCheck;
[SerializeField]
Transform jumpPos;



// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
    chara = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    playerTran = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Transform>();
  
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{
    chara.Move(moveVector);
    if (chara.isGrounded)
    {
        transform.LookAt(playerTran);
    }
    
    moveVector -= Vector3.up * gravity  * Time.deltaTime;
   

    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.J))

    {
        jumpCheck.position = new Vector3(playerTran.position.x, 0, playerTran.position.z);
        float angle = findAngle( playerTran.position.x - transform.position.x , playerTran.position.z - transform.position.z);
        Vector3 _toJumpPos = MakeJumpCricle(playerTran.position , jumpCheck.localScale.x/2, angle);

        jumpPos.position = new Vector3(_toJumpPos.x, 0, _toJumpPos.z);

        moveVector = Vector3.up * jumpForce * Time.deltaTime;
    }

   


}

float findAngle(float x, float y)
{
    float value;
    value = (float)((Mathf.Atan2(x, y) / Mathf.PI) * 180);
    if (value < 0)
    {
        value += 360;
    }
    Debug.Log(value);
    return value;
}

Vector3 MakeJumpCricle( Vector3 center, float radius, float angle)
{
    Vector3 pos = Vector3.zero;
    pos.x = center.x - radius * Mathf.Sin(angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
    pos.y = 0;
    pos.z = center.z - radius * Mathf.Cos(angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
    return pos;
}
```

I want to move the AI to the jumpPos with both forward and up vectors but I'm not sure to do this.

[visualization of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ypgX.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

[code visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMptn.jpg) 
I found a good solution, I used a Bezier Curves to generate a path

posting it here so other might find it helpful.

refrence link 
http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/bezier-curve-in-games

```
public LineRenderer jumpLine;


private int numberOfPoint = 50;
[SerializeField]
List<Vector3> pointPositions = new List<Vector3>();

CharacterController chara;

[SerializeField]
Transform playerTran;

[SerializeField]
float gravity = 3.8f;

[SerializeField]
float jumpForce = 50F;

Vector3 moveVector = Vector3.zero;

[SerializeField]
Transform jumpCheck;
[SerializeField]
Transform jumpPos;

[SerializeField]
Transform jumpHightOne;

bool movejump;

Vector3 pZero;
Vector3 pOne;
float time;


// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
    chara = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    playerTran = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Transform>();

    jumpLine.positionCount = numberOfPoint;
    jumpLine.gameObject.SetActive(false);



}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{
    chara.Move(moveVector);
    if (chara.isGrounded)
    {
        transform.LookAt(playerTran);
    }

    moveVector -= Vector3.up * gravity  * Time.deltaTime;


    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.J))

    {
        jumpCheck.position = new Vector3(playerTran.position.x, 0, playerTran.position.z);

        float angle = findAngle( playerTran.position.x - transform.position.x , playerTran.position.z - transform.position.z);
        Vector3 _toJumpPos = MakeJumpCricle(playerTran.position , jumpCheck.localScale.x/2, angle);

        Vector3 middlePoint = GetTheMiddlePoints(transform.position, playerTran.position, 0.5f);

        jumpHightOne.position = new Vector3(middlePoint.x, jumpHightOne.position.y, middlePoint.z);

        jumpPos.position = new Vector3(_toJumpPos.x, 0, _toJumpPos.z);
        //moveVector = Vector3.up * jumpForce * Time.deltaTime;
        //movejump = true;

        DrawLinerBezierCurves();
    }

    if (movejump)
    {
        //MoveTowardsTarget(jumpPos.position);
    }

}

Vector3 GetTheMiddlePoints(Vector3 origin, Vector3 destination, float middlepointfactor)
{
    return (destination - origin) * middlepointfactor + origin;
        // (destination - origin) * 0.5f; 
}


float findAngle(float x, float y)
{
    float value;
    value = (float)((Mathf.Atan2(x, y) / Mathf.PI) * 180);
    if (value < 0)
    {
        value += 360;
    }
    //Debug.Log(value);
    return value;
}

Vector3 MakeJumpCricle( Vector3 center, float radius, float angle)
{
    Vector3 pos = Vector3.zero;
    pos.x = center.x - radius * Mathf.Sin(angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
    pos.y = 0;
    pos.z = center.z - radius * Mathf.Cos(angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
    return pos;
}


void MoveTowardsTarget(Vector3 targetPostios)
{
    var offset = targetPostios - transform.position;

    if (offset.magnitude > .1f)
    {
        offset = offset.normalized * 15;
        chara.Move(offset * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    else
    {
        movejump = false;
    }

}


// line Bezier Curves
Vector3 CalculateBezierCurvesPoints(float t , Vector3 p0, Vector3 p1 )
{
    return p0 + t * (p1 - p0);
        // P = P0 + t(P1 – P0)  ,  0 < t < 1
}

// line Bezier Curves
Vector3 CalculateBezierCurvesPoints(float t, Vector3 p0, Vector3 p1, Vector3 p2)
{

    float u = 1 - t;
    float uu = u * u;
    float tt = t * t;

    Vector3 p = uu * p0;
    p = p + 2 * u * t * p1;
    p = p + tt * p2;
    return p;

    //P = (1-t)^2 P0 + 2 (1-t) t P1 + t^2 P2 , 0 < t < 1
    //     uu              u          tt
    //     uu   * p0  + 2 * u  * t * p1  + tt * p2  
}

void DrawLinerBezierCurves()
{
    if (pointPositions.Count > 0)
    {
        pointPositions.Clear();
        jumpLine.positionCount = 0;
        jumpLine.positionCount = numberOfPoint;

    }

    for (int i = 1; i < numberOfPoint + 1; i++)
    {
        float t = i / (float) numberOfPoint;

        if (!jumpLine.gameObject.activeInHierarchy)
        {
            jumpLine.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }

        pointPositions.Add(CalculateBezierCurvesPoints(t, transform.position,jumpHightOne.position, jumpPos.position));
        jumpLine.SetPosition(i - 1, pointPositions[i - 1]);
    }

}
```